# A user-input from an HTML box being used as a variable in a function that already has parameters

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

This is inside of the google suite of products, so I am using app script for all of my coding. The process of what I want to happen is as follows:

1. User wants to convert their document or whatever it is to a PDF
2. They press the drop down menu, which gives them options for PDF conversion of their document (currently there's only one option)
3. When pressing one of the options to run, a dialog box is created, asking for user input for which folder they want to put their PDF
4. The user then specifies which folder they want their newly made PDF to go to based on the UID of the folder

Because I can create a function within a function, I thought I'd be able to set a variable to the result of the function that was created WITHIN another function, but when trying to select the 'Export PDF' option, I get an unexpected error while getting the method getFolderById on object DriveApp. Below is the relevant code
JavaScript/App Script:

```
function exportAsPDF(){
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let blob = _getAsBlob(ss.getUrl())
  _exportBlob(blob, ss.getName())
}

function _exportBlob(blob, fileName){
  let folderUID = function getFolderUID(data){
    return data
  }
  blob = blob.setName(fileName)
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderUID)
  let pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob)

  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open "<a href="' + pdfFile.getUrl() + '" target=" _blank">' + fileName + '</a></p>').setWidth(375).setHeight(200)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Succesful')
}
```

HTML:

```
function getFolderUID(){
  let controls = {}
  validateInput(controls) ? google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).getFolderUID(controls) : window.alert('Please Enter a Folder UID')
}

function validateInput(controls){
  return controls["UID"].value != ''
}
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or the log of the unexpected error ?

Comment: In your Javascript, by `let controls = {}`, I think that an error occurs at `return controls["UID"].value != ''`. Because `UID` is not included in `controls` in the function `validateInput(controls)`. But, you say `when trying to select the 'Export PDF' option, I get an unexpected error while getting the method getFolderById on object DriveApp.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I was actually able to solve my issue by instead creating a dialog box by using the ```getResponseText()``` function built into App Script, as what I really cared about was the value the user entered